# Java Ledger API - return contractId in submit command

Tags: java, daml

Is there a way to automatically return the `contractId` generated by a command like:

```
client.getCommandSubmissionClient().submit(...).blockingGet();
```

If not, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way for finding the transaction you are looking for would be something like this:

```
client.getTransactionsClient()
  .getTransactions(LedgerOffset.LedgerBegin.getInstance(), new FiltersByParty(Collections.singletonMap(party, NoFilter.instance)), false)
  .filter(t => "MyCommandId".equals(t.getCommandId))
  .singleOrError()
  .blockingGet()
```

Note that here we are reading from `LedgerBegin`. Normally you would ask for the ledger end via `client.getTransactionsClient().getLedgerEnd()` before submitting the command and use the that offset for subscribing to transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried something like this, but this kind of command keeps throwing me connection timeout exceptions for some reason.

Comment: It might be that your command actually fails. Note that `client.getCommandSubmissionClient().submit(...)` cannot return a failure in all cases, due to the distributed asynchronous nature of command processing. You should rather use `client. getCommandClient(). submitAndWait(...)` which will track the command for you via the `completionStream`. That should give you a definitive answer on whether your command was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt synchronous API call that returns the resulting transaction of a (successful) command submission. The command service only returns the command completion (ie success/fail).

One way to do what you want is to use the `commandId` field. It allows the submitting party to correlate the command submission and resulting transaction. You would, however, have to build a wrapper combining the command and transaction services yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Also, do you think it's possible to provide an example of your suggestion?